# REGEX remove any kind of domain from a URL

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all the domain, in any format. I have all kind of url formats but i need to make sure I get only the URL content without the domain.

I receive URLS in any of these formats:

```
https://www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
http://www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
```

The result for any of these scenarios should always be:

```
asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
```

I have try to make myself but not getting 100% results

```
^[^#]*?:(\/\/).*?(?=\/)(\/)
```

Comment: Why use a library when regex can do that? Im using PHP by the way.

Comment: Isn't it better to use native PHP function? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

`^(?:\S+\.\S+?\/|\/)?(\S+)$`

The capturing group contains the required text. I am using alternation between the presence of a domain or not, and then capturing the rest of the part.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NJfetI/2)

Comment: Im using only `(?:\S+\.\S+?\/|\/)?` because i need to remove the domain from the url, the problem is its also removing any `/` from the url even if is out of this domain group, did you know why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got it! `^(?:\S+\.\S+?\/|\/)` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(https?:\/\/[^:\/\n?]+)\/(\S+)/i
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [builtin URL parser](https://www.php.net/parse_url). It isn't as compact, but it feels more robust and easier to maintain:

```
<?php

$urls = [
    'https://www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa',
    'http://www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa',
    'www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa',
    'asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa',
    '/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa',
    'asdfasd/fa/sd/fa',
    '../img/logo.png',
    'https://www.example.com/foo/bar?one=1&two=1#main',
    'https://www.example.com/?one=1',
    'https://www.example.com/#main',
    'http:///example.com',
    'http://:80',
    'http://user@:80',
];
$componentsWanted = [
    'path' => '',
    'query' => '?',
    'fragment' => '#',
];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $components = parse_url($url);
    if ($components === false) {
        echo "Could not parse URL: $url\n";
        continue;
    }
    $newUrl = '';
    foreach ($componentsWanted as $component => $prefix) {
        if (isset($components[$component])) {
            $newUrl .= $prefix . $components[$component];
        }
    }
    echo "$url -> $newUrl\n";
}
```

```
https://www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa -> /asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
http://www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa -> /asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa -> www.asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa -> asdfasd.com/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
/asdfasd/fa/sd/fa -> /asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
asdfasd/fa/sd/fa -> asdfasd/fa/sd/fa
../img/logo.png -> ../img/logo.png
https://www.example.com/foo/bar?one=1&two=1#main -> /foo/bar?one=1&two=1#main
https://www.example.com/?one=1 -> /?one=1
https://www.example.com/#main -> /#main
Could not parse URL: http:///example.com
Could not parse URL: http://:80
Could not parse URL: http://user@:80
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/23Kum)

<sub>(I'm sure it can be shortened even further with some fancy array functions.)</sub>